# Google Maps places services OVER_QUERY_LIMIT/Per Second

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are using Google Maps place service API. I have problem with over_query_limit. As per documentation the limit is 10 request per second.
But my application requires a minimum of 40 request per second.

Can I get Business google maps place service API with 40 request per second?

Comment: Can we get a Business maps API with 40 request/per second?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Maps API for Business FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#places_limits) Places API requests are not rate limited (if you're paying for it):

> If you've purchased the Google Places API as part of your Maps API for
>   Business contract, your Places API limits will be listed in the Quotas
>   section of the API console. Places API requests are not rate limited.